# How to copy a file and move it to a location using unix

Tags: shell, filenames, cp

I need a file to stay in the same location but also move it to a different location.
What am I doing wrong?

```
cp RubyTest.sublime-settings \
    ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/User
```

Comment: You aren't escaping the space between `Application` and `Support`.

Comment: I need it to stay in the same location but also move it to a different location @ Gabe thank you

Comment: Victoria: The word "copy" means to create a second file in another location with the same contents, leaving the original file as-is; the word "move" means change the location of a file so it is in the new place instead of the original place. You can't have both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put quotes around the path, but leave the `~` out of the quotes:

```
cp RubyTest.sublime-settings \
    ~/"Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User"
```

Within quotes, you can't use the `~` syntax, but you can use the longer `$HOME` instead:

```
cp RubyTest.sublime-settings \
    "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User"
```

Answer (score 1):

Stay in the same location and move to a different location is impossible - unless you are taling about a symbolic link.

`cp` will make a copy of your file to a new location without modifying the original version.

As the comment says, your big problem is spaces in file names.
Wrap your arguments to `cp` in quotes. The `~` character won't expand to your home directory if it's in quotes; either use `$HOME` instead (which is expanded in double quotes) or leave the `~` outside the quotes.

```
cp "RubyTest.sublime-settings" \
    "$HOME/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User"
cp "RubyTest.sublime-settings" \
    ~/"Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User"
```

Comment: There are *hard* links too.